# Setting State with Set Interval in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, setinterval, react-context, setstate

I have a async function that outputs an array.  I have a useeffect that has this function (get array) defined inside of it.  Then I call a timer inside the useeffect to continuously run the function.  I call the useeffect when I am focused on the given screen.

The console log from the function in the timer is showing the completed array.  Then I set the state.  But then my screen where I am showing the array in a flat list is not updating.

Why is the state not updating/showing the list on the screen?

```
useEffect(()=>{
        const getArray = (async()=>{
            arrayFound = await scanCycle()
            console.log('arrayFound',arrayFound)
            setArrayObjects(arrayFound)
            //await context.setAllDevs(arrayFound)
        })
        
        const timer2 = setInterval(()=>{
            
            getArray()
        },3000)
        return() => clearInterval( timer2 );
    },[isFocused2])
```

I have tried various other methodologies to useeffects and setIntervals.  I also have tried setting the state not locally but in a context which does work and renders the list.  However, when I set the state in the context, the memory used by the app starts to increase linearly leading to deprecation of the app.

Comment: I have created an example (https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/interval-update-screen).
Maybe ```setArrayObjects ``` and ```scanCycle``` raí se an error